# Maven trying to download '-sources.src' artifacts?

Tags: maven

I have a Maven project that so far used to compile without problems. Today, when I run `mvn clean package -U`, I get:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myproj: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.myorg.myproj:myproj:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:src:sources:3.0.1, org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:src:sources:8.1.2.v20120308, org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:src:sources:8.1.2.v20120308, org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:src:sources:8.1.2.v20120308, commons-io:commons-io:src:sources:2.4: Could not find artifact javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:src:sources:3.0.1 in MyRepo (http://maven.myorg.org:9001/nexus/content/repositories/myrepo/) -> [Help 1]

I tried to with a fresh local Maven repository (`rm -fr ~/.m2/repository`) but that did not make any difference.

Why does Maven try to find `source`/`src` artefacts? Any ideas where the problem might lie?

**Edit:** My dependencies (as seen using `mvn help:effective-pom`) do not have any `source` classifiers. For example, the dependency on the `jetty-server` mentioned in the error message reads as follows:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
  <version>8.1.2.v20120308</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Solution:** With the help of @AlessandroSantini and @brian-topping, I finally identified the problem. One of my indirect dependencies had a `<classifier>sources</classifier>` and `<type>src</type>`. (`mvn help:effective-pom` did not show these indirect dependencies, and `mvn dependency:tree` failed with the above error message, too; eventually, a `grep -r 'jetty-server' ~/.m2/repository/ -C 3` identified the artifact with the messed up dependency.)

It turned out that one of my own [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org) projects required the (non-existing) source artifacts for one of its dependencies: I used [SBT's `withSources()`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#download-sources) where I should have used [sbteclipe's `EclipseKeys.withSource := true`](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/wiki/Using-sbteclipse#wiki-withsource) to get the sources in Eclipse.

Comment: Perhaps you may include your pom.xml?

Comment: Apparently it looks like you have a "src" type and a "sources" qualifier in your dependency.

Comment: @AlessandroSantini, not sure: When I look at the complete dependencies, using `mvn help:effective-pom`, I do not see any dependency with a sources qualifier (see my edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any dependencies on public snapshots?  I'd take a look at the output of `mvn dependency:tree` and see if you can find a transitive dependency that is including the sources somehow.  Maybe one of the transitives have changed since your last build and *they* messed something up.

Comment: That sounds like a very promising track, thanks, Brian! Right now, I am struggling with `mvn dependency:tree`, which by itself fails with the same error message as in the post.

Comment: Thanks, Brian, your hint put me on the right track (see edit in OP for details).